Pass react-native UI Component to Android
For my React Native Android, I have created a Custom Camera Module which uses Camera2 API that I want to use in RN.
For the UI part of it, I want to pass it from the react-native side, but how can I pass it to my Android?
I created a separate UI module for this but I think this is a little overkill.


Create a React native View Component.
// It Is CameraOverlay Component 
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const CameraOverlay = () => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.overlay}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Camera Overlay</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
  },
  text: {
   color: 'white',
   fontSize: 20,
  },
});
export default CameraOverlay; 


Need to setup and create Native Module File.
// CustomCameraModule.java
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContext;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactContextBaseJavaModule;
import com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactMethod;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

public class CustomCameraModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  private final ReactApplication reactApplication;

  public CustomCameraModule(ReactApplication reactApplication) {
     super(reactApplication.getApplicationContext());
     this.reactApplication = reactApplication;
  }

  @Override
  public String getName() {
     return "CustomCameraModule";
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void showCameraOverlay() {
     // Create a new ReactRootView
     ReactRootView reactRootView = new ReactRootView(getCurrentActivity());
     reactRootView.startReactApplication(
         ((ReactNativeHost) reactApplication).getReactInstanceManager(),
         "CameraOverlay", //React Native component
         null // Initial properties
     );

     // Add the ReactRootView to your camera layout
     // Assuming you have a layout to which you want to add this view
     View cameraLayout = getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.camera_layout);
     cameraLayout.addView(reactRootView);
  }
}


The created model should be registered to the mainapplication.java.
import com.yourpackage.CustomCameraModule; // Import your module

 @Override
 protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
   return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
     new MainReactPackage(),
     new CustomCameraPackage() // Register your custom package
   );
 } 


It's time to use the native module when you've finished the three stages.
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

const { CustomCameraModule } = NativeModules;

// Call the method to show the camera overlay
CustomCameraModule.showCameraOverlay();



